# TinyMCE templates with floated DIV elements

Tags: html, templates, tinymce

TinyMCE templates (http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:template) can be used to pre-define the HTML inside TinyMCE.  For the real application, I would use content_css and a TinyMCE template, however, for the example below, I have used inline styling and hardcoded the HTML which produces the same results.  Consider http://fiddle.tinymce.com/BPeaab/1 with the following setup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
   <textarea name="content">
      <div style="float: left;">Left Div</div>
      <div style="float: right;">Right Div</div>
  </textarea>
</form>
```

The original HTML in the editor will be the following:

```
<body contenteditable="true" data-id="content" class="mce-content-body " id="tinymce" spellcheck="false">
   <div data-mce-style="float: left;" style="float: left;">Left Div</div>
   <div data-mce-style="float: right;" style="float: right;">Right Div</div>
</body>
```

If I then edit the content on the left `<div>`, and add press "enter", I desire to see the content in the editor have line breaks, however, instead each time I press "enter", a separate floated `<div>` is added and thus no line breaks.

```
<body contenteditable="true" data-id="content" class="mce-content-body " id="tinymce" spellcheck="false">
   <div data-mce-style="float: left;" style="float: left;">Left some text on first line.</div>
   <div data-mce-style="float: left;" style="float: left;">Some text on second line.</div>
   <div data-mce-style="float: left;" style="float: left;">
   <br data-mce-bogus="1"></div>
   <div data-mce-style="float: left;" style="float: left;">Some text on forth line.Div</div>
   <div data-mce-style="float: right;" style="float: right;">Right Div</div>
</body>
```

As a workaround, I have found that I could add `<p>` tags around the content in the floated `<div>` elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
   <textarea name="content">
      <div style="float: left;"><p>Left Div</p></div>
      <div style="float: right;"><p>Right Div</p></div>
  </textarea>
</form>
```

This latest attempt appears to create the desired results, however, expect it is not the proper way to do so.

```
<body contenteditable="true" data-id="content" class="mce-content-body " id="tinymce" spellcheck="false">
   <div data-mce-style="float: left;" style="float: left;">
      <p>Left Add some text.</p>
      <p>Add some text.</p>
      <p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
      <p>Add some text.</p><p>Div</p>
   </div>
   <div data-mce-style="float: right;" style="float: right;"><p>Right Div</p></div>
</body>
```

What is the proper way to add a TinyMCE template which contains floated `<div>` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This add-on helped me creating templates - [TinyMCE Templates](http://doksoft.com/soft/tinymce-templates/index.html).
Or you can try [TinyMCE Custom Templates](http://doksoft.com/soft/tinymce-custom-templates/index.html)  for more complicated templates.